# How can i suppport both Unicode and Multi-Byte Character Set in Static library (.lib)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unicode, multibyte

I am using visual studio 2015 and I want to write C++ static library that I can use in Unicode projects and in Multi-Byte projects, how I doing it right?

For example I have this code:

```
namespace Reg
{
    LONG WINAPI CreateKey(
        _In_  HKEY    hKey,
        _In_  LPCTSTR lpSubKey,
        _In_  REGSAM  samDesired,
        _Out_ PHKEY   phkResult
        )
    {
        return RegCreateKeyEx(hKey,
            lpSubKey,
            0, NULL,
            REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
            samDesired,
            NULL,
            phkResult,
            NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use a wchar_t interface and don't care about all the TCHAR business. It was a bad idea when it was invented, and it's a bad idea now. Not using the "wide" versions of the Windows APIs is just silly in any case.

Comment: You have to have two functions, Since this is C++, you can overload, so have two `CreateKey` functions, one that takes a `LPCWSTR` and one that takes a `LPCSTR`.

Comment: @RaymondChen can I have just one declaration that takes `LPCTSTR` and two definitions, one that takes a `LPCWSTR` and one that takes a `LPCSTR`?

Comment: @codeDom: No. Each function needs its own declaration and definition.

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried to compile with single declaration, and was successful. What it means?

Comment: It means that you compiled for only one character set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Raymond Chen suggested in a comment, you can use two separate overloaded functions - one for Ansi, one for Unicode:

```
namespace Reg
{
    LONG WINAPI CreateKey(
        _In_  HKEY    hKey,
        _In_  LPCSTR  lpSubKey,
        _In_  REGSAM  samDesired,
        _Out_ PHKEY   phkResult
        )
    {
        return RegCreateKeyExA(hKey,
            lpSubKey,
            0, NULL,
            REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
            samDesired,
            NULL,
            phkResult,
            NULL);
    }

    LONG WINAPI CreateKey(
        _In_  HKEY    hKey,
        _In_  LPCWSTR lpSubKey,
        _In_  REGSAM  samDesired,
        _Out_ PHKEY   phkResult
        )
    {
        return RegCreateKeyExW(hKey,
            lpSubKey,
            0, NULL,
            REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
            samDesired,
            NULL,
            phkResult,
            NULL);
    }
}
```

Or, like rubenvb suggested, just forget about the Ansi function altogether, focus on just Unicode by itself:

```
namespace Reg
{
    LONG WINAPI CreateKey(
        _In_  HKEY    hKey,
        _In_  LPCWSTR lpSubKey,
        _In_  REGSAM  samDesired,
        _Out_ PHKEY   phkResult
        )
    {
        return RegCreateKeyExW(hKey,
            lpSubKey,
            0, NULL,
            REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
            samDesired,
            NULL,
            phkResult,
            NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do it same way as is usually  used for Win32 functions:

```
CreateKeyW(..)  { unicode implementation }
CreateKeyA(..) { byte string implementation }
#ifdef UNICODE
#define CreateKey CreateKeyW
#else
#define CreateKey CreateKeyA
#endif
```

Comment: I would use C++ function overloading instead of C macros.  Those #define statements in the Win32 API cause all kinds of problems in 3rd party libraries, so best to avoid causing the same problems in your own code.